# Making a function that takes as an input a list not care about the order of the elements of the list

Tags: list-manipulation, sets

I would like a function f, that takes as input a list, not care about the order of elements of the list. So,for example:

> f[{3,2}]=f[{2,3}]

Is this possible? Or is it necessary to convert the list into a set? If so how can I the conversion be done?

Thank you in advance

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. Please give an example of what such a function should do with `f[{x,y}]`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`OrderlessPatternSequence`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OrderlessPatternSequence.html):

```
ClearAll[f1]
f1[{OrderlessPatternSequence[x_, y_, z_]}] := {{{x}, {z}, {y}}}

f1[{2, 3, 1}]
```

> {{{1}, {3}, {2}}}

```
f1[{3, 2, 1}]
```

> {{{1}, {3}, {2}}}

You can use it with a subset of arguments:

```
ClearAll[f2]
f2[arg1_, OrderlessPatternSequence[x_, y_, z_], arg2_List] := {x, y, z, arg1, arg2}

f2[t, 2, 1, 3, {x}]
```

> {1, 2, 3, t, {x}}

```
f2[t, 1, 2, 3, {x}]
```

> {1, 2, 3, t, {x}}

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you want to compare lists for equality using `==` (not `=`), but ignoring order. There are many ways. One way is to make a new kind of list wrapper:

```
SetAttributes[orderlessList, Orderless]
```

You need not define any values for `orderlessList`: it's just a wrapper. Now, a conversion from `List` to `orderlessList`:

orderless[x_List] := Apply[orderlessList, x]

Then,

```
orderless[{3, 2}] == orderless[{2, 3}]
(* True *)
```